# Валидация 0 для Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть проблема с валидацией значений, проверяю заполнено-ли поле

```
export const required = value => {
    if(value) return undefined;
    return `Введите обязательное поле`;
}
```

Но когда там значение 0 для стандартного значения, проверка срабатывает как будто поле пустое

Comment: Кстати, вместо `return undefined;` можно писать просто `return;`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (value == ""){
    return `Введите обязательное поле`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

0 являетса логически false в java script

А функцыя Number(false) даст 0

Поэтому можно  выводить прямо в HTML  этотже
 Number(false) иначе 0

Если "undefined" то стандарт можно записать как 
Var txt = null 
но в этом случаи строка будет пустая